Why is my thermostat not dropping a degree
Would this use more electric? We had a new thermostat installed and whatever it is set on that's where it stays. It will not drop one degree. It will stay off 12 minutes and kicks back on in 6 minutes. My other thermostat would always drop a degree and stay off a while. Do you think this is normal? It stays at 77 degrees and will not move off that number. The air conditioner guy says it's doing it's job correctly.  I just don't think so.  We are senior citizens and can't afford I'm sure this big electric bill when we get it. I would love to know your answer.

Different thermostats will have different set and trigger points, and different ranges of dead band. Let me explain.
Imagine a thermostat that is set at 77F, and with a  tiny dead band, that is, a very small differential between the set point (77.0000F) and the trigger point (77.0001). The thermostat would be constantly starting up the A/C and then shutting off after a few seconds, then cycling again. This will prematurely wear down your equipment. On the other extreme, imagine a thermostat set at 77F, but with a trigger point at 90F. You would have to spend a lot of time at uncomfortable temperatures before the A/C would be triggered, then wait for the A/C to run for an hour before it reaches the set point and shuts off. Both of these extremes are undesirable, so thermostats have dead bands somewhere between those two extremes.
So what you are seeing is that your new thermostat has a narrower dead band (ie a shorter differential between the set and trigger points), so that it's triggering at say 77.4, and running the A/C until it reaches 77 (or 76.6 or whatever). Your old thermostat had a larger dead band, with a trigger at 77.4 and a cut-off (set) point at 76.0 (or whatever.)
The new thermostat is not costing you more money.

If your old one drops a degree below where it's set at, it's cooling more than you wanted it to and will cost you money. It will save you money by not coming on as fast because it's cooler. Mine turns off at what I had it sent to. Every unit I've ever had has done the same thing. Keep in mine that each thermostat, temperature guage, has it's own degree of accuracy, plus or minus one, or two degrees so correlating between different units really becomes usless.

More and more, they've discovered that it's possible to make HVAC that is most efficient when it runs frequently, making small temperature changes.  Older thermostats triggered less often and made larger temperature changes.  The difference that you're seeing is simply going from an older thermostat and system to a newer one.
If you want to reduce the electricity cost, you can turn up the temperature.  The new system will hold the temperature better, so you can run it with a higher temperature than the old system and still stay in the same comfort range.  I.e. if your old system ran 76-78 when you targeted 77, you spent part of the time overcool at 76.  If 78 was good enough, you can set the new system at 78 and consistently keep that temperature.
My experience though is that the newer systems actually run more cheaply than the older systems, so your electric bill may be lower than you expect.  Both the fans and the part of the system that makes the air cold run more efficiently and therefore cheaper.  The fans actually run more slowly, using less electricity even though they run more often.  And the cooler runs in a more narrow range, not bothering to get as cold as the old systems needed to get down to the lower temperature.
Your experience so far matches mine after the new HVAC was installed last year.  If it continues to do so, you'll find that the new system actually uses less electricity than the old.  Your utility may already be able to tell this.  Mine can show me my daily usage and compare it to last year's.  Note that if the outside temperature is higher, you may get higher usage from that.  You need to compare days with similar temperatures.
